# what replaced PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode in Windows 10 mobile

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-universal

basically I want to stop the lockscreen from kicking in on a windows 10 app while my app is running on windows phone 7+ it was PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode now I cant seem to find a replacement.

Comment: Does the answer help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the **`DisplayRequest`** class.

When a display request is activated, the device's display remains on while the app is visible. When the user moves the app out of the foreground, the system deactivates the app's display requests and reactivates them when the app returns to the foreground.

Ref: 
[DisplayRequest class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.system.display.displayrequest.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)

Sample code:

```
var dr = new DisplayRequest();
dr.RequestActive();
//  ...
dr.RequestRelease();
```